# Debian 7 Shutdown Beep

Tags: linux, networking, debian-wheezy

How can I disable the beep when I reboot Debian 7?  I have gone into `/etc/inputrc` and made the console not beep and have muted `Beep` in a`lsamixer` but it still happens. I have seen reference to blacklisting the `pcspeaker` module but am not sure I want to kill that all together, I just want to kill this particular alert.

**Edit** So, it seems this might have something to do with the networking.  I was also fixing it so that the wired connection was not trying to connect at boot and, therefore, delaying the boot while DHCP timed out.  Fixing that seems to have made the beep go away.  Even though the beep is gone, I would still love to understand the **why** behind all this.  I posted a pastebin link in a comment below of what was happening during reboot while the beep was still happening.

Comment: /etc/inputrc is the wrong source to look at. Use `strace` to identify the evil beeper. It reminds me of an old keyboard in ca. 1987, it made a short beep with every keystroke. You could disable with some command, but it came back after every reboot. One day later I opened the keyboard and cut the speaker's cables. The sound of silence.

Comment: So, I tried the strace thing... couldn't find the answer there but here is what it gave in case someone else can. [http://pastebin.com/77vhYtNT](http://pastebin.com/77vhYtNT)

Comment: There it is in line 317: the write `\7\r\n`. Can you look at the source if it can be turned off?

Comment: @ott-- So, I looked at the line you referenced but I am not understanding... do you mind elaborating or pointing me to something that explains what you are saying?  Thanks!

Comment: I meant you should look into reboot's source code to see if it the beep could be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked on my LMDE (Linux Mint Debian). Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add this line:

```
options snd_hda_intel beep_mode=0
```

Here are some of the other things I tried in case that one does not cut it:

1. Blacklist `pcspkr`, this is not a big deal by the way, you can still hear movies etc it is just the onboard speaker that produces the beep that is disabled:

   ```
   echo "blacklist pcspkr" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
   ```

   sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
2. Add this to `/etc/gdm3/greeter.gconf-defaults`:

   ```
   gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/sound/event_sounds false
   ```
3. Depending on what is causing the beep (is it reboot, or login or what?) this might work, it disables the terminal warning bell:

   ```
    xset b off
   ```

Comment: I had already tried the xset one... no luck.  Thank you for the info though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying beep and found a patch on the [debian bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614893). So I decided to have a look at it. The patch will remove a `\007` from a file called `dowall.c` which will be include in the shutdown binary.

I read the [debian handbook page for rebuilding a package from source](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/debian-packaging.html#sect.rebuilding-package) and built the sysvinit package for me with the patch applied.

This package contains a lot of important stuff and I was to scared to install the package. (It is my first package I built for debian) :) That's why I only extracted the shutdown binary file from the package and moved it to `/sbin/shutdown`.

Afterwards the annoying beep was gone...